# geolocation with inteactiv markers

Tags: database, google-maps, gps, markers

I'm attempting to create a mobile app with the following purposes:
1. display geolocation with watchpostion so that the location marker moves with you across the map.
2. display markers with interactive* infowindows along the map wich are at solid locations.
3. have direction availability so that it shows the route from geolocation to position of the marker of your choice.
* with interactive I mean I wish for the marker to contain an import from database function. The database will display the current price of the Product of interest available on the various markerpoints within the chosen zoom-area and highlight the marker with the lowest price so that you may select to gt direction to the location with the best offer.
I have been able to create the watchposition() map itself and creating an infowindow displaying on a fixed map. However those two are working in to individual Projects, but when I try to put them together the preview goes blank. How to make them work together? I'm using myeclipse 2015 stable version

Comment: please paste some code samples and try to edit your question to make it more readable, so people can help you here

Comment: Here is the code for geolocation I wish to add markers in:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for geolocation I wish to add markers in:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geolocation watchPosition()</title>

<!-- for mobile view -->
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // you can specify the default lat long
    var map,
        currentPositionMarker,
        mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(57.736585899999994, 12.956377999999999), 
        map;

    // change the zoom if you want
    function initializeMap()
    {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
           zoom: 18,
           center: mapCenter,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         });
    }

    function locError(error) {
        // tell the user if the current position could not be located
        alert("The current position could not be found!");
    }

    // current position of the user
    function setCurrentPosition(pos) {
        currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                pos.coords.latitude,
                pos.coords.longitude
            ),
            title: "Current Position"
        });
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                pos.coords.latitude,
                pos.coords.longitude 
            ));
    }

    function displayAndWatch(position) {

        // set current position
        setCurrentPosition(position);

        // watch position
        watchCurrentPosition();
    }

    function watchCurrentPosition() {
        var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            function (position) {
                setMarkerPosition(
                    currentPositionMarker,
                    position
                );
            });
    }

    function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
        marker.setPosition(
            new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.coords.latitude,
                position.coords.longitude)
        );
    }

    function initLocationProcedure() {
        initializeMap();
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);
        } else {
            // tell the user if a browser doesn't support this amazing API
            alert("Your browser does not support the Geolocation API!");
        }
    }

    // initialize with a little help of jQuery
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initLocationProcedure();
    });

</script>
```

```
<!-- display the map here, you can changed the height or style -->
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:25em; margin:0; padding:0;"></div>
```